# Update key value pair dynamically in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am writing a groovy script which can take input from a workspace which is already a git repository, detect the branch, and update the branch value in json format:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def content = """
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "repos" : [{
    "name": "service-config",
    "source_root": "/service-config",
    "mountpoint": "test",
    "url" : "http://test.example.com",
    "include_branch_name" : "false",
    "branches" : [""],
    "hooks": [{
      "type": "polling",
      "interval": "15"
    }]
  }]
}"""

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)
builder.content.repos.branches = 'kunal'
println(builder.toPrettyString())
```

But it's not printing the actual value.

See here: [gist.github.com/thatsk/0bd61635dc510660fa8f93975dbd8fc0](http://gist.github.com/thatsk/0bd61635dc510660fa8f93975dbd8fc0)

Comment: So right now what's the status; what's happening ?

Comment: its not printing actual value.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thatsk/0bd61635dc510660fa8f93975dbd8fc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just update your parsed json object before building(writing) it :

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def content = '''
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "repos" : [{
    "name": "service-config",
    "source_root": "/service-config",
    "mountpoint": "test",
    "url" : "http://test.example.com",
    "include_branch_name" : "false",
    "branches" : [""],
    "hooks": [{
      "type": "polling",
      "interval": "15"
    }]
  }]
}'''

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
slurped.repos[0].branches = ['kunal'] //array because you have an array in original json
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)
println(builder.toPrettyString())
```

Comment: when i am trying to add branch using shell command using groovy its printing \n infront of branch value.

Comment: it's because you have new line in the output (`cout` variable). you could trim spaces by this: `"${cout.trim()}"`

Comment: Why did you remove the quotes? `"..."`

Comment: `"${cout.trim()}"` is just `cout.trim()`; reading the branch can be shortended to `'git name-rev --name-only HEAD'.execute().text.trim()`. Also while the gists are nice to share progress, the question/answer lose context. Could you be bothered to add your progress to the question instead?

Comment: nope i wanted to understand all terminology and trying to adopt all concept

Comment: @cfrick its showing same issue which is showing for cout.trim(). i know we are only changing way of trimming .but actually trim method is not found. why this is happening. is there anything missing

Comment: Ah, you have court declared as StringBuilder. This should work: `cout.toString().trim()`